# How to find a substring or a char in an array of strings in Julia

Tags: string, performance, julia

Whats a more efficient way to do the same thing that the next line of code is doing:

```
X = ["Please", "Thx", "Hello", "World"]
findfirst(k->occursin('H',k)==true,X)
```

So basically i'm trying to find the first element of the array X that has the uppercase letter H, so in the example the output is 3, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: This is an efficient code. The only thing is that you could remove `== true` (but it will not affect the performance).

Comment: you can use `contains` and make it look a bit nicer : `findfirst(contains('H'),X)`

Comment: If `X` is a constant or does not change too much at runtime, then you can optimize this a bit (especially if `X` is bigger in practice).

Comment: I guess `contains` it's faster, based on the answer below, and `X` it could be bigger, my code finds chemical elements in ecuations, so i have to iterate over `'H'` to find diferent elements in the array `X` (which contains the ecuations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something fundamental here, check out the timings below:

```
julia> @time findfirst(k->occursin('H',k),X)
  0.015461 seconds (11.20 k allocations: 689.455 KiB, 99.63% compilation time)
3

julia> @time findfirst(contains('H'),X)
  0.000008 seconds
3
```

Seems like the `contains` route is significantly more performant than `occursin`.

Comment: Testing the `occursin` and `contains` functions all alone in the same case gives me that occursin i'ts faster, i guess the improvement in time comes from not having to declare an implicit function to make `contains` work, just as a fun fact this is, so thanks for answering.